# How To Neatly Cover an Indoor Sewer Cleanout?

Tags: plumbing, sewer, cleanout

I am currently renovating my room and realized that there is a wall popping out. It was bothering me because it would be an obstruction when placing new furnitures. I removed it and planned to make the cover as small as possible so any ideas on covering a Sewer Cleanout?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Make a bench or small table to cover it, cannot be moved so it is best to figure a way to hide it that will work with your decorating / furnishings.

Comment: Looks like it was covered before...what was wrong with that cover?